# Patch notes for 2.8 beta?

Tags: windows, versions, documentation, development

Where I can see it? Doesnt seem to find anywhere. And new updates are released every day it seems? Should I update Blender every day too? Afraiding of that something will be broke in updates, like recent sss for eevee.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2.80 is not finished yet. If you are afraid of something broken, you should not use experimental builds. There are broken things in them - that's a fact. So you should not do anything about 2.80, but you can if you want to and you can download it every day if you wish - you would get some updates daily because they are built pretty much every day(see the build dates at the download page). 2.79b version is stable and complete and you should use it for work that you cannot afford to get broken at some point.

If you wish to keep up to date with the development, you can see links on this page: https://www.blender.org/get-involved/developers/. You can find [Blender Developers Blog](https://code.blender.org/) there, you can even see developer [Weekly Meeting Notes](https://devtalk.blender.org/c/blender/meeting-notes). There is also this guy doing [Blender Today Live streams on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=%23BlenderToday). You will also find many discussions some unavoidably about 2.80 on [BlenderArtists.org forums](https://blenderartists.org/)